# Why it is necessary to believe in God?

Tags: belief

For anyone why it is necessary to believe in God? What one is getting with this belief? Please don't give heaven/hell or judgment day as the reason.

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer: Because believing in the truth is better than not believing in the truth.  You might as well just ask "Why is it necessary to believe that the Earth is round?"

God doesn't need our belief: He exists whether we believe in Him or not.

Comment: The question explicitly asked for no mention of the judgement day as an argument.

Comment: @user5751924 OP changed his question after I'd already posted the answer. I've adjusted my answer to suit.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say what other people get out of it, but I can tell you what I get out of it. I get humbled, I get patience, I get values, I get morals, I get wisdom, I get trust, I get positive, I get optimistic, I get hope, and I get reason. It's hard to get all that during one's life because we are very much susceptible to bad judgment, superstition, and self-destructing tendencies.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in Islam. The live my life in a positive way.
I never questioned, because I was from the beginning. I was born with it to believe in it and it has done me very well. (Not that I'm forced but I have seen peace in Islam) there was a duscissie about a man and a woman

man said what if the Islam is not true

woman answered, even if it is not true (which I do not believe) I've lived a positive life and have no regrets

which gave the man answer as:
is it not bad to find out after death thats not true (that the god doesn't exist)

To which the woman replied laughing: it's much worse than that you die and find out that it does exist.

conclusion I was born a Muslim and I am proud to lead a positive life